# How to load a tif image in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, image, tiff

How can i read a .tif image as a Image widget in flutter?

Since tif is not supported by default in flutter, there is any package or method that can load and decode a tif image?

Answer (score 0):

Saw this kind of question some time ago...

You can decode the image and encode it as png like

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as imgLib;
imgLib.Decoder dec = imgLib.findDecoderForData(response.data);
Image.memory(imgLib.encodePng(dec.decodeImage(response.data)))
```

You can then display the png in Image.

Cheers!!

Comment: Right, but should i load the image as a Widget, as a File or load de Bytes on (response.data).
I've seen this answer but it doesn't help very much. Can you please put it with a little bit more context? Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Since response.data is a String and findDecoderForData expects a List<int> which are the raw bytes. Further on findDecoderForData returns a imgLib.Decoder?. Turns out for my tiff images the decoder is always null.  Please give a further explanation on how this worked for you? Is some type of decoding the res.data needed?

Answer (score 0):

If the response data is String, this code snippet work for me

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as imgLib;
final dec = imgLib.findDecoderForData(base64Decode(url));
Image.memory(
              Uint8List.fromList(
                  imgLib.encodeJpg(dec!.decodeImage(base64Decode(url))!)),
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the image package to do it.

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as imgLib;

//use this to load the tiff file based on the file path
await imgLib.decodeTiffFile('assets/test.tif');
```

But when I used the above method, it keep mentioning that the file path does not exist. So, I changed a bit and used the following method.

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as imgLib;

final filePath = 'assets/test.tif';
final data = await rootBundle.load(filePath);
Uint8List audioUint8List = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
final map = await imgLib.decodeTiff(audioUint8List);
```

I have to read the file using root bundle, converting it to Uint8List as decode function only read Uint8List, then read it with the function decodeTiff.

Hope it helps.